# Ways to simplify passing down members to contained classes (in C++)

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I've looked around but couldn't find what I'm looking for (not sure what keywords to use). I'm working on a C++ project myself. This project has `window`s, `page`s and `field`s. A `window` can contain one or more `page`s, and a `page` can contain one or more `field`s. What's shared across the `window`, `page` and `field` is they have an `InputManager` which takes care of all the IO of the user. The `InputManager` can act on the window, the page and the field (for example, some inputs act directly on the `page`, while some act on the `field`). Also, a `field` can generate `status` messages to be displayed at a location of the containing `window`.

Right now I have the following structure, but it doesn't seem optimal. There's a lot of pointer passing down, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do so.

```
class InputManager
{
    //do stuff to return input
}

class StatusManager
{
    //do stuff to display statuses
}

class Field
{
    friend class Page;
protected:
    InputManager *input_manager;
    StatusManager *status_manager;

    /*
    other methods that do stuff that 
    may recieve from input_manager and 
    send statuses through the status_manager
    */
}

class Page
{
    friend class Window;
protected:
    vector<Field* > fields;
    InputManager *input_manager;
    StatusManager *status_manager;
public:
    AddField(Field *field)
    {
        field->input_manager = this->input_manager;
        field->status_manager = this->status_manager;
    }
}

class Window
{
protected:
    vector<Page *> pages;
    InputManager *input_manager;
    StatusManager *status_manager;
public:
    Window()
    {
        input_manager = new InputManager();
        status_manager = new StatusManager();
    }

    AddPage(Page *page)
    {
        page->input_manager = this->input_manager;
        page->status_manager = this->status_manager;
    }
}
```

If I want to learn more about these types of problem, what keywords or fields should I be looking into?

Comment: Try to use `unique_ptr` instead of `new`

Comment: An alternative is to pass the input and status objects to the methods that need them, but it's a little hard to say whether that is better overall in your case.

Comment: @MooingDuck Okay. At the moment I'm limited to C++0x, but I'll keep that in mind for future developments

Comment: @VaughnCato Could you explain a bit more? Are you talking about Dependency Injection?

Comment: I mean having `Field::method(InputManager&,StatusManager&)`, and requiring the `Field` user to pass the `InputManager` and `StatusManager` parameters when `Field::method` is called instead of storing them inside the Field.

Comment: @silentwf: You probably mean C++03.  C++0x was used to refer to the upcoming version after 03, before it came out.  It came C++0x finalized in 2011, so its final name C++11. Likewise, C++1y got split into C++14 and C++17. (Curiously, C++17 came out in 2016...)

Comment: @VaughnCato For my application I think it might be better to store it, since I have other member functions that will need to access the InputManager

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh okay. Confusion here. Something learned again :)